# How to access C structs with a union within a struct

Tags: c, struct, unions

I am working with someone else's C code, where they have defined the following:

```
typedef struct {

  union{

    struct{
      int A;    // some data
     } structA;

    struct{
       char B;  // some alternative data
    } structB;

  } myUnion;

} myStruct;
```

Youch.  Earlier in the code, these mega-structs are declared, malloc'ed, and populated with data.  I am working on a later section of code where I'll be passed a pointer to one of these structs and have to (A) determine if type structA or structB was used, and then (B) read the actual data.  Something like:

```
void myFunction(myStruct *s){

   if(s->myUnion.structA != NULL)      // compilation error here
      printf("This myStruct uses a structA, internal data is: %d\n", s->myUnion.structA.A);
   else
      printf("This myStruct uses a structB, internal data is: %c\n", s->myUnion.structB.B);

}
```

Obviously the above doesn't compile:

```
me@Linux:/home/me# gcc -Wall structsUnions.c
structsUnions.c: In function 'myFunction':
structsUnions.c:22:19: error: invalid operands to binary != (have 'struct <anonymous>' and 'void *')
   if(s->myUnion.structA != NULL)
                         ^
me@Linux:/home/me#
```

But I'm at wit's end trying to figure out the syntax here.

There's got to be a way of peaking into a myStruct and determining if a structA or structB is inside the myUnion.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The term to look for is "tagged union".

Comment: In your code you are comparing structA to NULL, structA isn't a pointer, a union allows the contents, in your case structA and structB to share the same memory.  You can't tell which is used because they are the same, all you can do is be clever about how you use them, include an identifier in structure to identify the union content.  You access a union in exactly the same way as you would a structure.

Comment: `s->myUnion.structA` is a struct - you want `s->myUnion.structA.A` to access the value

Comment: The only thing in your example that could possibly be dynamically allocated, and hence possibly `NULL`, is the top-level structure itself, for which you would use `if (s != NULL)`.  If you want to know which union was used, you would need to add a field to the top-level structure that specifies that information.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to store extra identifying information inside the struct. You could store the information outside the struct. But you need to pass that information along with the struct in any code that needs to find out which union is currently being used.

Comment: The code has to be designed/written to not switch internal items in a union you have to stick with one until no longer needed so if you get passed a union and dont know then additional information has to be passed along as well, really no way around it.

Comment: @old_timer Yeah, after carefully reading what everyone has had to say, I'm beginning to think you're right.  The author of the original code must have had some unseen mechanism so the code could guess in advance if the inner struct was A or B.  Or he/she was a bad coder.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code you shared doesn't include a tag field indicating whether the `A` or `B` member is actually used, there's no concrete way of knowing for sure which one was intended in any particular instance.

However, depending on the data you're getting, you *may* be able to make an educated guess in your code. For example, say I have the following union on a system that uses IEEE 754 for floating point types:

```
typedef union _F_or_I
{
    float f;
    int32_t i;
    uint32_t bits;
} F_or_I;
```

If the first 9 bits (the sign and the exponent) are all 0, it's probably not a floating point number:

```
F_or_I foo = /* some value */;

if(!(foo.bits & 0xFF800000))
{
      // access member 'i'
}
else
{
      // access member 'f'
}
```

Of course, this way is not always accurate depending on the exact type(s) you're using in the union (I wouldn't even rely on it for the types used in my example!), and the correct way to do this is to include a 'tag' member in the parent `struct` that indicates which member of the union is intended to be accessed.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't like "educated guess" and "probably". Either the user of the struct knows for some external reason what the struct contains, or the struct should contain a tag field.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I conceded that point in my answer. I am just including the "educated guess" and "probably" stuff in the chance that the struct and union definition are beyond the programmer's control and a guess *must* be made.

Comment: @GovindParmar I think you're correct.  I'm starting to think that the original author of my code baked in some unseen mechanisms on whether the inner A or B struct was used.  Or was a bad coder.  Thanks!

Comment: Never try to "guess" which union member is active.  Always use an independent field that indicates which member is defined.  Regarding the claim that an all-zero exponent "probably" indicates a non-float, that's simply not true:  an IEEE zero is represented by all zero bits.  I can't think of a more commonly-seen floating pointer number.

Comment: @TomKarzes If the value was zero it wouldn't matter whether it was treated as `int` or `float`

Comment: @GovindParmar Why wouldn't it?  Perhaps if it's float I do one thing, and if it's an int I do another.  Just because they have the same mathematical value makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

myUnion is a `union`, not a structure with two members.
It means `structA` and `structB` share the same memory (in most C implementations).
It also means `char B` and `int A` share the same memory (again, in most C implementations), so there's virtually no way to tell which of the constructs is used.
The ANSI defines that a union is at least as big as it’s biggest member, and that it is required to hold one of the members.
It aims for an efficient implementation to reuse the same memory for all members.
Of course, in some implementations alignment issues may cause some members not to overlap others, but I can’t think of a single one I know that doesn't align by the biggest member.

Comment: whether or not char B and int A share/overlap the same memory locations is implementation defined, not assumed.

Comment: @old_timer It is well-defined that they share the same memory, but we can't know if the char corresponds to the MS byte or something else, since that depends on endianess. And of course, using char which has implementation-defined signedness, for this purpose, is a bad thing to do.

Comment: @old_timer This was new to me, so I went up and dug the ANSI for this, all I could find was: "The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its members.", but in reality (and the ANSI aims for that) - there is not a single implementation that doesn't share memory for union members and I doubt if such will ever arise (unless somebody comes up with a C implementation in javascript or something). I did find this in the GNU C reference: "... Since all of the members of a union occupy the same memory space..."

Comment: how it is shared is implementation defined, highly likely if not required that char B and int A overlap exactly how is implementation defined. the int could be considered 32 bit but the compiler could align everything on 64 bit boundaries leaving a hole, but the char would probably be aligned the same way but technically could land in the hole.  unlikely.  so the statement that they share the same memory is not incorrect and I think per spec but exactly how and certainly not in a way to detect which struct was used, the code simply has to be designed for that...

Comment: just need to be careful about implying the connection between items in a union there is a lot of bad code coming from chip vendors incorrectly using unions these days, need to turn that habit around and get back to sanity.

Comment: @old_timer Technically - you are right, while I don't know of any compiler vendor that would implement this differently (alignment is currently done for the biggest member, as far as I know) - I agree that relying on the shared memory assumption is a bad habit.

Comment: bitfields are the biggest problem/sin.  the 8, 16, 32, 64 bit items tend to be predictable or at least once you see an implementation it makes sense biggest member down and such, sane alignments based on architecture.

Answer (score 1):

In particular, the compilation error in `if(s->myUnion.structA != NULL)` is because you cannot check if the struct is null but only if a member of the struct is zero:

```
if(s->myUnion.structA.A != 0)
```